# SQLiteDatabase Tables not created in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sqlite, sqlite

I've been trying to build a database application with search facility modelled after `SearchableDictionary` in Android Samples:

**The helper class is as following:**

```
public class DataBaseTable {

public static String DATABASE_NAME ="DICTIONARY";
public static int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private final DatabaseOpenHelper datahelper;
public static String TAG="Databse";
public static String COL_DEFINITION="DEFINITION";
public static String COL_WORD="WORD";
public static String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE="FTS";

public DataBaseTable(Context context) {
    datahelper=new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}
private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private Context mHelperContext;
    private String FTS_TABLE_CREATE="CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +" USING fts3 (" +COL_WORD + ", " +COL_DEFINITION + ");";


    DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DICTIONARY ("+ COL_WORD+ " , "+COL_DEFINITION+");");
        db.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);

    }




    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);


    }
}
```

And from the `MainActivity`, I call `DatabaseTable db=new DatabaseTable(this);` in `onCreate(Bundle)` method. But I can see no databases in the emulator `FileExplorer`.

Did I miss something?

**EDIT:**
The MainActivity is as following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DataBaseTable db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db=new DataBaseTable(this);
        handeIntent(getIntent());

    }


    private void handeIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Cursor c = db.getMatch(query, null);
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.def};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.info, c, null, to, 0);
        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handeIntent(intent);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code from `MainActivity`. Also look at logcat if there are errors or exception tracebacks. If so, show them as well

Comment: Logcat shows no errors/exception. Which is why I keep wondering whether the Database helper class is called.

Comment: You can use a debugger or logging to test if class is called (but I think it is). Have you looked at the right directory for the db which should be something like "/data/data/<app package>/databases" (if I remember correctly)?

Comment: Thanks for the logging tip. The logging in `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` doesn't show up in Logcat. Isn't that supposed to run on start of helper class?

Comment: Yes, except if the database was already created and you just didn't look for it in the right place

Comment: After the running of the program on multiple emulators in different computers, _/data/data/com.example.searchview_ consists of just a `cache` and `lib` folders. There is no sign of databases. The application installation details confirms that there is no data associated with the app. I am going to start from the scratch. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think I overlooked something: In your `DataBaseTable` constructor (or maybe elsewhere) there must be a call to `datahelper.getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` alternatively

Answer (score 1):

Take help from here 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

You need to inherit the database class SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have inherited the database class in the inner class.